# How to truncate the second column to given length

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Given input of the form

```
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar foolkasjfdrte
```

how can I truncate only the second column? The delimiter is TAB and the second column must be at most 75 characters long.

Comment: A bit more generic: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} {$2=substr($2,1,75)}1' file`

Comment: Do you want to truncate (delete characters after the 75th) or fold (print them on another line)? Also, should the spaces be counted towards the 75 characters or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to print only the first 75 characters of the second column (including spaces, and assuming only two columns in the file), you can do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\t.{75}).*/$1/' file
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar fool
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\t.\{75\}\).*/\1/' file
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar fool
```

Or:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*\t.{75}).*/\1/' file
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar fool
```

Alternatively,  you could use `fold`, telling it to cut at the first 91 characters (that's 8 for the identifier and another 8 for the tab), and printing only the first line:

```
$ fold -w 91 file | head -n1
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar fool
```

---

If your file can have more than 2 columns and you only want to truncate the second, you can do (which, as I just noticed, is just a rewording of [Stephen's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202691/22222)):

```
$ awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" '{$2=substr($2,1,75)}1;' file
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar fool
```

Or (note that this will break if the first 75 characters of the 2nd column can be interpreted as a regular expression):

```
$ perl -F"\t" -pale 's/$F[1]/substr($F[1],0,75)/e' file
XY981743    foobarlkasdf saflkas asfZR!sgfad asdSAD asdsadf SAdfasdf46lk lksad bar fool
```

Comment: Those may truncate an other columns than the second one. Your first `sed` command is also using a GNUism (`\t`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas _what_? `\t` is a GNUism? Seriously? What is the portable way of describing a tab then?

Comment: Insert it verbatim of see my answer. The only escape sequence recognised portably on the LHS is `\n` (and again not inside `[...]` with many implementations), none on the RHS.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas damn, thanks. I also added a solution which can handle multiple columns.

Comment: Your last `perl` one makes little sense. Think for instance of an input like `aba\t.*`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas true, I added a disclaimer. The OP doesn't say so explicitly, but the format they show is one that is often used to store biological sequence data and I was working under the (quite possibly mistaken) assumption that the text will be alphanumeric. I know the example shown is not, but the spaces and general format are really reminiscent of NCBI flat files.

Answer (score 12):

Using `awk`, split the file using tabs and output the first field in full and the first 75 characters (at most) of the second:

```
awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }; { print $1, substr($2, 1, 75); }'
```

As pointed out by [fedorqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/40596/fedorqui), you can handle files with more than two fields by replacing the fields you need to truncate:

```
awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }; { $2=substr($2, 1, 75); print }'
```

You could apply the `substr` to multiple fields by looping over them if necessary.

Comment: @Stéphane, in which cases are the extra `;` necessary?

Comment: They are required by POSIX. Now I don't know of any implementation where they are required, but when I asked that that POSIX requirement be relaxed, [it was rejected by the gawk maintainer](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226#c2226) (where all examples in the doc have the ;).

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks! So the spec and the documentation are stricter than all the implementations...

Comment: _all the implementations_ that I know of at least (not  so many). The point is omitting the delimiter makes for non-standard syntax. So current and future implementations may and are entitled to choke on it or introduce extensions that make use of it (like an exception handling one `/pattern/ {action} {exception-handling}` for instance). Now that would be extremely unlikely given that omitting those `;` is fairly common.

Comment: this messed up my columns, but can be fixed eg. awk 'BEGIN { OFS=" " }; { $2=substr($2, 1, 75); print }'  | column -t

Answer (score 4):

Portably/POSIXly with `sed`:

```
tab=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/\($tab[^$tab]\{0,75\}\)[^$tab]*/\1/"
```

Or to truncate every column:

```
sed "s/\([^$tab]\{75\}\)[^$tab]*/\1/g"
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are *only* 2 columns:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t)(.{0,75}).*/\1\2/'
```

`{0,75}` means select from 0 up to 75 chars.
`.*`     is the removed section beyond char 75.

---

If there are 2 *or more* columns:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t)([^\t]{0,75})[^\t]*(.*)/\1\2\3/' file
```

`[^\t]*` is the removed section beyond char 75.

Comment: Note that that assumes GNU `sed` and that `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is not in the environment..